# Strange "Column reference 'xxx' is ambiguous" for single-table query

Tags: postgresql

Inside a function there is a simple single table query:

```
create function myfunction(...)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
...
return query select 1, variable1, xtcol1 from xtable where xtcolx=variablex;
...
```

when running it `select myfunction(...)` got

```
ERROR:  column reference "xtcol1" is ambiguous 
LINE 1: select 1, variable1, xtcol1 from xtable ...
                                ^ 
DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column. 
QUERY:  ... 
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function myfunction(integer,character varying) line 20 at RETURN QUERY
SQL state: 42702
```

Surely I can fix it by prefix every column in the query, but it makes no sense because I named all columns with a unique table abbreviation. For example `xtable` abbreviation is `xt` so there is no ambiguous columns across the board. It works out well in all other functions except this. Postgre v12

Comment: `DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.` It seems that you have function's parameter/variable with same name

Comment: @Abelisto confirmed no param or variables matching exactly the same name, except in the `RETURNS TABLE(..., xtcol1 character varying)`

Comment: Yes `TABLE(...)` columns also treated as `OUT` parameters which could be used inside the function's body like `xtcol1 := 'foo'` so you should to qualify them by table or function name.

Comment: @Abelisto Sounds like pg is unable to distinguish between the `RETURN TABLE(... xtcol1)` and the `return query select ..., xtcol from ...` in the function body. Does it mean I can use the former inside function body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so error message :

> DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.

shows you are passing a parameter with the same name as your column,

so how about you escape it :

```
select 1, variable1, "xtcol1" from xtable ...
```

Comment: Confirmed no param or variables matching exactly the same name, except in the `RETURNS TABLE(..., xtcol1 character varying)`. Double-quote it works! What is this **escape** do?

Comment: @Jeb50 yeah , still its a variable . you can escape any database object name ( like column names , table names, etc) to be distinguished from anything else ,like from database keywords or reserved word and etc. in your case , we tell the sql engine , this is a column not anything else

Comment: I can't see how that solves anything. quotes distinguish names from keywords,  but the problem here is that there are two things with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is to qualify the ambiguous name with either the table (alias) or the function name:

```
SELECT xtable.xtcol1 FROM xtable
```